# Spark JDBC data fetch Optimization from relational database

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

a) Is there a way in which Spark can optimize the data fetch from a Relational Database when compared to a traditional java JDBC call.
b) How to reduce the load on the database while running Spark queries as we will be hitting production database directly for all queries.  Assume 30 million order records and 150 million order line records in Production for the Spark reporting case.

Answer (score 0):

Re a)

- You can of course .cache() the data frame in your Spark app to avoid repeated executions of the JDBC for that data frame during life time of your Spark app
- You can read the data frame in via range partitioned parallel JDBC calls using partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound and numPartitions properties. This makes sense for distributed (partitioned) database backends.
- You can use an integrated Spark cluster with a distributed database engine such as IBM dashDB, which runs Spark executors co-located with the database partitions and exercises local IPC data exchange mechanisms between Spark and the database: https://ibmdatawarehousing.wordpress.com/category/theme-ibm-data-warehouse/

b) Above mentioned Spark-side caching can help if applicable. In addition JDBC data source in Spark does try to push down projections and filter predicated from your Spark SQL / data frame operations to the underlying SQL database. Check the resulting SQLs that hit the database.